# How to make a div stacked on the top of a "fixed positioned" element (which contains a full screen background slideshow)?

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed

[**JSFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/06tayyvx/5/)

So in my SSCCE I have an `ul` with `position:fixed` and `background-size:cover` set. This `ul` contains 6 `span`s, with `background` images, to be displayed as a slideshow.

[I followed this tutorial to make this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/). ([Demo here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/))

Now i have some more content to add to the page. **I want it to be kinda [displayed like this](https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php)** (i.e. the slideshow should be fixed in the background, and the rest of the content should be hovering over it-scrolling if needed.) - [Tutorial here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

**I had aniticipated** that if I create a div for the rest of the content under the `ul` containing the slideshow in the mark up, I'd get the desired result - since in the CSS-Tricks demo I have linked, the background-image is applied to the `<html>` which has a `fixed` position and no `position` is applied to the rest of the content (so `static` by default), and in my code also the `ul` has a fixed position. **But my content seems to be stacked under the slideshow?**

**So what can I do to make the `#content-below-slider` div to be stacked on the `ul` containing the slideshow, and not beneath it?**

---

***What I tried:***

I tried applying a `z-index:10000;` to `#content-below-slider`, but that did not make any difference. I have no clue what else to do.

I understand the `position:fixed` elements are out of flow of the page and hover on top of the rest of the page, but then why doesn't it happen in the CSS-tricks demo. What should I do?

---

***Note:-*** I did not post the code as anyone reading the question will check the Fiddle linked anyway, so it would probably make the question unnecessarily long. If you think I should post the code here as well, let me know.

Comment: Thank you so very much. This works. I'll appreciate more if you can tell why? To the best of my knowledge, z-index only works in relation to other elements' values for `z-index`, that is an element with `z-index` less than that of another element's will be stacked under the other element, and doesn't have to do with whether the value is positive or negative. Isn't it?

Comment: 1/ z-index has no effect on non-positioned elements (with default `position:static`, no effect ; with relative, fixed, absolute then it has an effect) 2/ teh stacking context or [Understanding CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index) on MDN (IE6/7 were completely messed up but who cares anymore and IE8/9 have problems with pseudo `:before` and `:after`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could add this CSS to #content-below-slider (sorry if i don't understand you and this is not what you want): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xrqn6nm/)

```
#content-below-slider {
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Just adding `position:relative;` worked. Thank you! Please remove the rest of the two properties as that will confuse the future visitors.